# Why does input-field disappear when resizing window

Tags: html, css

When I resize my browser window the input field is cut off a bit. I am using percentages but it still is being cut off and I do not know why. I have provided a screenshot below.[image: Screenshot] If I am using percentages shouldn't it resize automatically? Thank you!

Here is my css code:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.homepage-window {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-bar {
    width: 18%;
    background-color: #2E3E4E;
}

.bar-manager {
    width: 100%;
}

.top-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
}

.top-bar p {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.user-search-input-field {
    margin-left: 70%;
    width: 190px;
    background-color: red;
}

.bottom-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    line-height: 40%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.bottom-bar h1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.bottom-bar p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Homepage.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<head>
    <title>Cold-Ops Homepage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="homepage-window">
        <div class="nav-bar">   
        </div>
        <div class="bar-manager">
            <div class="top-bar">
                <p>Homepage</p>
                <div class="user-search-input-field">
                    <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
                        <input type="text" name="userPost" placeholder="Search users..." required>
                        <i class = "fa fa-search" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-bar">
                <div class="bottom-bar-texts">
                    <div><h1>Welcome, Omard2000</h1></div>
                    <div><p>Administrator</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've positioned the element.

It's possible that the left is pushing it off the visible screen

Also, mixing view units and pixels is dangerous.

Comment: I don't understand. I know that I positioned it to be on the top left, but when I resize the window the input field is cut off.

Comment: Positioning is relative to the parent if it has been given position by CSS (normally position: relative) and the element is block or replacement.

Your parent doesn't appear to have position set. 

Your left is percentage. Your width is pixels. Your earlier CSS used view height units. 

Pick view units or pixels, not both. Set position relative on the parent element (this matters).

Comment: Oh okay! Thank you so much! I'm going to go ahead and fix this now.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Post:**

> becouse of this `user-search-input-field` not enough space. `top-bar` divide into two parts,part1 for `p` and part2 for `user-search-input-field` with more space. like this:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EFEFEF;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.homepage-window {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-bar {
    width: 18%;
    background-color: #2E3E4E;
}

.bar-manager {
    width: 100%;
}

.top-bar {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid lightgrey;
}

.top-bar p {
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}


.bottom-bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    line-height: 40%;
    background-color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.bottom-bar h1 {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.bottom-bar p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

.user-search-input-field {
    width: 100%;
    
}

form {
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

.top-bar p {
    width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="homepage-window">
    <div class="nav-bar"></div>
    <div class="bar-manager">
        <div class="top-bar">
            <p>Homepage</p>
            <div class="user-search-input-field">
                <form action="Login.php" method="POST">
                    <input type="text" name="userPost" placeholder="Search users..." required>
                    <i class = "fa fa-search" aria-hidden = "true"></i>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-bar">
            <div class="bottom-bar-texts">
                <div><h1>Welcome, Omard2000</h1></div>
                <div><p>Administrator</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```